# ORACLE и ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql-developer

Базу в итоге поднял и Listener тоже , но как только я хочу подключится к базе через web приложение
После вода логина и пароля сразу падает Listener , что делать и куда копать не знаю. Через sqlplus и Pl/Sql Developer все коннектится и работает как часы.
Web приложение выдает ошибку:

```
Ошибка при запросе:
ORA-12541: TNS:нет прослушивателя
Неизвестный код ошибки ответа: WARNING_CONNECT_DB
```

Снова поднимаю Listener , опять подключась через web и снова такая ошибка. Help!

---

```
21-AUG-2018 12:02:56 * service_update * rrc * 0
Tue Aug 21 12:03:06 2018
System parameter file is /oracle/app/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /oracle/app/diag/tnslsnr/mis3/listener/alert/log.xml
Trace information written to /oracle/app/diag/tnslsnr/mis3/listener/trace/ora_21568_140123659904768.trc
Trace level is currently 0

Started with pid=21568
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mis3.detstvo.rrc)(PORT=1521)))
Listener completed notification to CRS on start

TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN CODE
WARNING: Subscription for node down event still pending
21-AUG-2018 12:03:06 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=mis3.detstvo.rrc)(USER=oracle))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=186646784)) * status * 0
WARNING: Subscription for node down event still pending
21-AUG-2018 12:03:08 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=mis3.detstvo.rrc)(USER=oracle))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=186646784)) * status * 0
```

Comment: проверьте фаервол

Comment: sudo service iptables stop. Отключил его полностью такая же фигня.

Comment: Чисто теоретически ошибка понятна . Не запущен Listener , но почему Web приложение его(Listener) заваливает непонятно.

Comment: Какие ошибки в логах Listener’а? Какая у вас версия Oracle? Можете ли вы подключиться к экземпляру БД с помощью sqlplus, используя service_name / oracle_sid после получения данной ошибки?

Comment: Версия oracle 11.2.0 . Нет после получения данной ошибки sqlplus пишет ERROR: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener , да оно и понятно т.к Web приложение завалило Listener уже. /oracle/app/diag/tnslsnr/mis3/listener/alert/log.xml  . Логи отсюда нужны?

Comment: Какие ошибки в $ORACLE_HOME/network/log/listener. log ?